# Android view weight regardless of text

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to create a table of 2*X in size and I want the columns to be equal in width. How do i accomplish this? I have tried both LinearLayout and a tabelLayout which both works fine as long as the text on each radio button is the same but when this is not the case they split the space unevenly (even tho there is room for the text with and equal split). I have thought about setting the width during run time but my getWidth() returns 0. Help would be much appreciated.

Ps. I'm not using XML

Code:

```
imports....
public class SpendoRadioGroup extends LinearLayout implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
private GUI_attrs gui_attrs;
private RadioButton[] buttons;
private RadioButton selected = null;
public SpendoRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    gui_attrs = new GUI_attrs(context, attrs);

    this.setBackgroundColor(gui_attrs.color_Z1);
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    this.setPadding(gui_attrs.padding_Z1, gui_attrs.padding_Z1/2, gui_attrs.padding_Z1, gui_attrs.padding_Z1/2);


    RadioButton[] btns = new RadioButton[2];
    btns[0] = new RadioButton(context);
    btns[0].setText("Item 1");
    btns[1] = new RadioButton(context);
    btns[1].setText("Itemes 2");

    this.setRadioButtons(btns, "Instruction:");
}
public void setRadioButtons(RadioButton[] buttons, String instruction){
    this.removeAllViews();

    TextView tvInstruction = new  TextView(gui_attrs.context);
    tvInstruction.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tvInstruction.setText(instruction);
    tvInstruction.setTextSize(gui_attrs.textSize_tiny);
    this.addView(tvInstruction);

    this.buttons = buttons;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    param.weight = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(gui_attrs.color_Z2);
        buttons[i].setLayoutParams(param);
        buttons[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    LinearLayout row;
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length/2; i++){
        row = new LinearLayout(gui_attrs.context);
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        row.setBackgroundColor(gui_attrs.color_Z1);
        if(i == 0){
            row.setPadding(0, 0, 0, gui_attrs.padding_Z1/2);
        }else{
            row.setPadding(0, gui_attrs.padding_Z1/2, 0, gui_attrs.padding_Z1/2);
        }

        row.addView(buttons[i*2]);

        TextView tvDiv = new TextView(gui_attrs.context);
        tvDiv.setPadding(gui_attrs.padding_Z1, 0, 0, 0);
        tvDiv.setBackgroundColor(gui_attrs.color_Z1);
        row.addView(tvDiv);

        row.addView(buttons[i*2+1]);
        this.addView(row);
    }
    if(buttons.length%2 > 0){
        row = new LinearLayout(gui_attrs.context);
        row.setBackgroundColor(gui_attrs.color_Z1);
        row.setPadding(gui_attrs.padding_Z1, gui_attrs.padding_Z1/2, gui_attrs.padding_Z1, gui_attrs.padding_Z1/2);

        param = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param.weight = 0.8f;

        TextView tvDiv = new TextView(gui_attrs.context);
        tvDiv.setLayoutParams(param);
        row.addView(tvDiv);

        buttons[buttons.length-1].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        row.addView(buttons[buttons.length-1]);

        tvDiv = new TextView(gui_attrs.context);
        tvDiv.setLayoutParams(param);
        row.addView(tvDiv);

        this.addView(row);
    }

}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean checked) {
    if(checked){
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            if(!buttons[i].equals(view)){
                buttons[i].setChecked(false);
            }else{
                selected = buttons[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
public void createRadioButtons(String[] text, String instruction){
    RadioButton[] buttons = new RadioButton[text.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        buttons[i] = new RadioButton(gui_attrs.context);
        buttons[i].setText(text[i]);
    }
    this.setRadioButtons(buttons, instruction);
}
public String getSelected(){
    return selected.getText().toString();
}

///Failed attempt...
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate (){
    super.onFinishInflate();

    System.out.println("Finnish inflate: " + this.getWidth());
}


}
```

Comment: getWidth() will return 0 until the view has already been drawn, you can use a ViewTreeObserver for that. In order to help you more some code would be helpful.

Comment: Added the code :) I'll read up on ViewTreeObserver

Comment: you can use Handler will some time delay too for calculating the height of buttons.

Comment: I'm trying to add a OnDrawListener but get the newAPI warning. Is there a compatibility library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless if you use XML to layout your screen or do it programmatically. The RadioButtons, Texts etc. are distributed first with their size and then only the resulting free space is evenly distributed between the Views of the LinearLayout.

**Example**: You have a horizontally orientated LinearLayout with two Views in it. The first View has a width of 48dip, the second one with 12dip. Both have the same weight and the LinearLayout is 96dip wide.

**Androids Layout for the example**: What happens is, that Android gives both views what they need and calculates the free space between them as `96dip - (48dip+12dip) = 36dip`. Now the 36dip are evenly distributed between the two views `= 18dip` for each. Each View now is positioned within the space of its own width + 18dip. Where the View will be positioned depends on the `layout_gravity`.

If you need evenly sized Views within a LinearLayout, you give them the same weight AND set their width (horizontally distributed) or height (vertically distributed) to `"0dip"`.

Said all that, you must define the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` exactly this way. In your example that means the code for evenly sized columns is:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, height, 1f);
```

Note, that the `width`parameter is set to 0 so that all available space of the LinearLayout is evenly distributed between Views.

Comment: Great thanks! Not only for the answer but also for the thorough explanation, this is something which I've had trouble with several times and never quite understood why the programming god made it work this time or that time :)